# DataSet truncates decimal points to 2 digits

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, truncation

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that returns a column named "LienAlloc_Amt" of type money.
In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), a record returns "LienAlloc_Amt" value of "85.226" (3 decimals).  But when I retrieve the value from C# code using DataSet, only "85.22" is set.

[image]

Why is "LienAlloc_Amt" is truncated when the dataSet object is filled?

Comment: Double check the `Columns` on your `DataTable`. It may be that it came in as a different type and inadvertently got truncated.

Comment: We could also help more if you could show us the body of your stored proc.

Comment: @TyCobb When I checked the datatype of the column, it was `System.Decimal`.

Comment: I converted the type of "LienAlloc_Amt" from type `money` to `float`.  It seems to have done the trick.  I am getting $85.226!

Answer (score 0):

check what is the return type of your procedure, side of application. maybe you cast this type into class, so this may cause problem.Try auto generated type.